# XSL: Pass string value to template match

Tags: java, xslt

I want to pass xpath string from java to XSL template. I tried these

```
<xsl:template
      match="string($fullxpath)">

<xsl:template
      match="$fullxpath">
```

This works

```
xpath value: <xsl:text/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$fullxpath" />
```

But the match does not work. Help Please !!

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not possible, you will need to learn to distinguish between attributes that allow an XPath `expression` to compute a value (like `select` of `xsl:value-of` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#value-of ) and attributes which are `patterns` (like `match` of `xsl:template` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#defining-templates).

In XSLT 3 however there is one new option of so called shadow attributes https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes together with static parameters https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="pattern1" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'foo/bar'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template _match="{$pattern1}"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMM

As you can see, the shadow attribute `_match` is set to the static parameter value.

A different, more complex approach, but also possible in XSLT 3 and Saxon 9.8 all editions or other compliant XSLT 3 implementations is generating a new stylesheet as needed and executing it with the `transform` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-transform. You need to generate the stylesheet code in XSLT with a different namespace you can alias to the XSLT namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-Alias"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="pattern1" as="xs:string" select="'foo/bar'"/>

  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

  <xsl:variable name="stylesheet">
      <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
          <axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
          <axsl:template match="{$pattern1}"/>
      </axsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="transform(
                              map {
                                 'source-node' : .,
                                 'stylesheet-node' : $stylesheet
                              }
                            )?output"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMM/2

Comment: thanks for the input. Option 1 with shadow attribute wont work. as the value is not static. xpath value will be passed from java dynamically. Am yet to try https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-transform.

Comment: A static parameter can be set from Java before running the stylesheet. Not sure what "passed from java dynamically" means, is XSLT calling into Java and Java returns that XPath expression as a string?

Comment: Java class passes the xpath to XSLT to be used in the template match.  Java `transformer.setParameter("fullxpath",fullxpath);`   I got this error when trying out Option 1   `XPST0008: Variables (other than XSLT 3.0 static variables) cannot be used in a static`

Comment: I think if you want to set static parameters from Java with Saxon 9.8 then this is possible with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#setParameter-net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue-, that means, if you use the s9api and not the JAXP API. You might want to add a tag for Saxon so that Saxonica/Michael Kay picks up your question and can give you more details on the API use.

Comment: @Ben, I have also now added an example on using XSLT 3 to generate XSLT and execute it in one transformation based on `xsl:namespace-alias` and the `transform` function from XPath 3.1.

Comment: @Mark I get this error `Element xsl:mode must not appear directly within xsl:stylesheet` for '<axsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>' . And if i remove that line, the elements dont show up. Only the text within the element is displayed in the output

Comment: I have posted suggestions based on XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1, currently implemented in the Java world by Saxon 9.8 (available in the open-source HE edition on Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.8/ and on Maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE), I am not sure in what context you get that error but it doesn't sound like an error of an XSLT 3 processor. If you indeed use Saxon 9.8 and get an error with the above suggestion and can't resolve it on your own, then better ask a new question with all details of your code and your used software.

Comment: Thanks, your transform example was good. And helped me get pass my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
<xsl:template
      match="*[name() = $fullxpath]">
```

?

It means, "match on any element, but with the condition that their name is equals to the variable fullxpath's text content"

Comment: what i meant is - instead of `<xsl:template
      match="/abc/efg">` want to use `<xsl:template
      match="$fullxpath">`  where `fullxpath = /abd/efg`